# Pymssql: Calling Stored Procedure with parameters

Tags: python, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using [pymssql](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/) to make database calls to a SQL 2005 database. I want to pass parameters to a stored procedure. I am having a hard time getting the correct syntax for that. Here is what I have for calling a procedure with no parameters:

```
import _mssql
connection = _mssql.connect(server='myserver', database='mydatabase', trusted=True)
connection.execute_query('storedProcedureName')
```

Suppose I wanted to set the @Id parameter to 1. How would I do that? The following lines do not work. The docs are unclear as to how the params are structured.

```
connection.execute_query('storedProcedureName', {'@Id':'1'})
connection.execute_query('storedProcedureName', '@Id=1')
connection.execute_query('storedProcedureName', ('@Id', '1'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the correct syntax to do this:

```
connection.execute_query('exec storedProcedureName @Id=1')
```

Comment: Be very careful to protect yourself from SQL injections.  I'm not in a place to test but it looks like what you want is something like connection.execute_query('exec storedProcedureName @Id=%d',(1,))

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wanted to make my example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone using a newer version of `pymssql`, you can call procedures with parameters like this: `cursor.callproc('storedProcedureName', (1,))`

Where the second parameter is a tuple of all the parameters required.

Comment: string arguments exceeding 8000 characters are currrently breaking.